# Export binary data from MS Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have an ms access database file (.mdb) with two columns:
Id with Data Type 'Short Text'
Image with Data type 'Long Text'

The db has about 1000 entries and it's file size is about 50 Mb, so I know the images are there.

But whenever I try to export the data (and in MS Access itself) all I see is "II*" for the image field.

I know nothing about mdb files, how in the world do I extract that data?  Ideally I want base64 encoding, but I'll settle for anything at this point.

Update 7-5-2022

I write a C# program to read the data and it is in some form of encoding I don't recognize.  The originator of the data says they "opened the tiff image in Binary mode and stored it in the string in MS Access".  So I guess the question is how does MS Access encode binary data being saved directly into a Long Text field.

Here's a snippet of the text stored:
[image]

Update 7-6-2022

They used the VB FileSystemObject to "open in binary mode" and save to the text field.  So I guess however that object decided to encode the binary data as a string, is how it is being stored.  #sigh
Trying to see if I can reverse the process

Comment: Long Text is not an image field, so the images must be somewhere else.

Comment: Does MDB have OLEObject data type field?

Comment: The images are somehow in that field however.  I can tell because if I delete all columns except that one, the db file size is roughly the same.  If I delete just that one field, the file size goes super small.  So maybe the images are encoded into that field somehow?

Comment: That looks messy. The `\u00nn` are probably encoded bytes (unprintable characters?), the other characters are the bytes themselves. The `\0` at the beginning may be encoded null bytes or not.

Comment: Following on what @Andre wrote, are you sure it's not encoded with UTF-16 (LE or BE)? If you could provide a copy-pastable snippet, readers might be more keen to try things out to help you.